# How to enable mouse popup in QtCharts?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I need a small popup be shown when the mouse hovers over series in my QtChart.

Highcharts (Javascript) has some really nice examples like this one:

[image]

How can I implement this QtCharts?

I cannot find any documentation on implementing popups.

Comment: Check out the [Qt callout example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-callout-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you will have to do it by yourself. I needed exactly the same and used a simple QWidget embedded in a QGraphicsProxyWidget that I added to the QGraphicsScene of the chart view.

```
QWidget *popup = new MyPopUpWidget;
QChartView v;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = v.scene()->addWidget(popup);

// if you want a drop shadow you can use QGraphicsDropShadowEffect
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* shadow   = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
shadow->setOffset(0, 4);
shadow->setBlurRadius(8);
proxy->setGraphicsEffect(shadow);
```

While this is nice and simple, the positioning of the popup is the actual work. All the simple solutions weren't good enough for me. For example there are signals if your mouse hits a QGraphicsItem (all line items of your charts are QGraphicsItems) but they are usually to small and you only want to react on the actual data points, not on the line segments.

You can override your mouseMove(QMouseMoveEvent *) function and always check your mouse position against all data points and adjust your popup (show/hide, positioning). If you have many points that will be slow, so I used a spatial grid and assigned data points to grid cells initially. Then you only need to check against points within the grid cells around your mouse position.

I didn't find a better solution.

Comment: could you show you code? I really dont know where to start. There aren't many good examples on this topic.